# How does a map of two categorical operads induce a map of categories of generalized multicategories?

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory, operads

I'm working on a project and I have two categorical operads with a free $\Sigma_n$ action and there exists a map of operads between them. I know via a paper by Elmendorf and others titled "Left Adjoints for Generalized Multicategories" that these categorical operads induce a category of generalized multicategories. I am wondering should it induce a map between these two generaized multicategories?

Comment: Usually all this kind of constructions are functorial so yes it should. What is it that prevents you from defining the induced map between the generalized multicategories ?

Comment: Well suppose I have two categorical operads with a free $\Sigma_n$ action.  Well we get that they induces a category of  generalized multicategories in the sense that Elmendorf lays out. Now suppose you have a map between the two operads (call it $F$). Also, say $T$ is our supposed functor. My problem is defining $T(F)$. I suppose we should pick our generalized multicategory, say $\mathcal{C},$  and define $T(F)(\mathcal{C})$ and pick a map between generalized multicategories, say $\hat F$, and define $T(F)(\hat F)$ but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: Maybe try to imrpove your question by giving the construction of induced category of generalized multicategories and, if you don't solve the question by doing this, at least you will put the finger on the concrete step your are not able to take.